# Is it possible to specify the MIME content-type for mobile devices?

Tags: email, content-type, mime

I'm sending an email that uses the `text/x-amp-html` (AMP Email) content-type, but I'm wondering if it's possible to force another content-type, `text/html`, on mobile devices. Is it possible to specify the MIME content-type for mobile devices?

Comment: Good question. I don't think that's possible. In any case, your question is related to the email sending service, not to amp-emails. It is also worth exploring the possibilities of email clients, such as gmail.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Good points. I removed the `amp-email` tag. So far, I have not discovered a way to do this, but my team and I have decided to move forward with using media-queries to achieve our desired result.